# What's wrong here?

Tags: complex-numbers, fake-proofs

$$i=\sqrt{-1}=\sqrt{\frac{1}{-1}}=\frac{1}{i}=\frac{-i^2}{i}=-i$$

I'm sure there is a mistake above but I can't figure out where. What's exactly wrong in the above situation & why?

Comment: why $\sqrt{-1}=i$ and not $-i$?

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/49169/why-sqrt-1-times-1-neq-sqrt-12.

Comment: otherwise $2i=0$ which is impossible

Comment: The main problem is using $\sqrt{x}$ on negative numbers and expecting it to behave nicely. Note that what you've really found here is that $(i)^2=(-i)^2=-1$

Comment: @ Arthur The answer you are getting is same as i,-i are conjugates and square of conjugates is same

Comment: What fails is $\sqrt {ab}=\sqrt a\,\sqrt b $. Not true in general for complex numbers.

Comment: Are people seriously still answering this question? If you can't be bothered with looking for one of the many duplicates, don't  answer at all. It doesn't help anyone.

Comment: @GitGud Next time I'll check for an available answer. Would it be better to delete this question now?

Comment: @Omur You should always check for duplicates before asking, but I'm not blaming you as you seem to be a new user. I would delete the question, but that's my personal opinion, I'm no authority here.

Comment: $\sqrt x$ returns the +ve square root, but complex numbers are unordered: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1116022/can-a-complex-number-ever-be-considered-bigger-or-smaller-than-a-real-number/1117231#1117231

Answer (score 1):

In general (at least as soon as complex numbers are involved), $\sqrt{ab}\ne\sqrt a\sqrt b$. Similarly $\sqrt{\frac1{-1}}\ne\frac{\sqrt 1}{\sqrt{-1}}$