# Evaluating line integrals that are analytic "almost everywhere" using Cauchy's Theorem or Integral Formula?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

First off: I know that "almost everywhere" has a legitimate meaning in measure theory, but I'm not referring to that in this case, really. I'm talking about the case where there are only a small (finite) number of points where the function is not analytic inside a piecewise-smooth simple closed curve.

I am wondering why we can't use Cauchy's Integral Formula or Cauchy's theorem in this case.

Some examples of what I'm referring to:

a) $\int_\gamma f(z) dz = \int_\gamma \frac{e^{z^2}}{z(z-2)}dz$ where $\gamma(t) = 3+2e^{it}$, $0 \leq t \leq 2pi$

b) $\int_\gamma g(z) dz=\int_\gamma \frac{z^2 - 1}{z^2 + 1}$ where $\gamma(t) = 1-i+2e^{it}$, $0 \leq t \leq 2pi$

In the first instance, $f$ is analytic on $\mathbb{C} \setminus \{2\}$ but unfortunately, the curve $\gamma$, which is the circle of radius $2$ centred at $3$, includes this point.

In the second instance, $g$ is analytic on $\mathbb{C} \setminus \{i, -i\}$ but, the curve, which is the circle of radius $2$ centred at $1-i$, includes these points.

I used WolframAlpha to evaluate the second integral using the standard definition of a line integral for a smooth curve, and got that the result is $2\pi$.

**My question is, why does having a small number of "holes" make the integral evaluate to a larger number (if there weren't any holes, it would have evaluated to 0 from Cauchy's Theorem)? It seems counterintuitive (given my understanding of integration in the reals).**

Also, are there any tips or tricks for attacking these types of integrals? They are difficult to work with (computationally) which is why I was hoping to find a way to use some of the nicer formulae.

Comment: You'll want the residue theorem or the integral formula to evaluate these.

Comment: If $f$ has only one pole on $|z|=1$ at $z=1$ and is meromorphic on $|z| < 1.1$ then $\int_{|z|=1} f(z)dz$ is ill-defined however  $$PV(\int_{|z|=1} f(z)dz)=\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \int_{|z|=1, |z-1|> \epsilon} f(z)dz = \frac12 \lim_{\epsilon \to 0}( \int_{|z|=1-\epsilon} f(z)dz+  \int_{|z|=1+\epsilon} f(z)dz)$$ The RHS integrals are evaluated with the residue theorem. The keywords are 'principal value residue' @SeanRoberson

Comment: Way more advanced than you're probably looking for, but possibly related is this [29 December 2004 sci.math post](http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=3426757) of mine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To begin with, none of the points are on the actual curves, i.e

---

a) $\gamma(t)=3+2e^{it}, 0\leq t\leq 2pi$ is

[image]

So $z_0=2$ is inside the disk surrounded by $\gamma$ ($0$ isn't). In this case [Cauchy's integral formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula#Theorem) applies
$$f(z_0)=\frac{1}{2\pi i } \int\limits_{\gamma}\frac{f(z)}{z-z_0}dz \tag{1}$$
where $f(z)=\frac{e^{z^2}}{z}$. Or 
$$\int\limits_{\gamma}\frac{e^{z^2}}{z(z-2)}dz=2 \pi i \cdot f(2)=\pi i e^4$$

---

b) $\gamma(t)=1-i+2e^{it}, 0\leq t\leq 2pi$ is

[image]

So $z_0=-i$ is inside the disk surrounded by $\gamma$ ($i$ isn't). [Cauchy's integral formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula#Theorem) $(1)$ applies again for $f(z)=\frac{z^2-1}{z-i}$. Or
$$\int\limits_{\gamma}\frac{z^2-1}{z^2+1}dz=2 \pi i \cdot f(-i)=2 \pi i \frac{-1-1}{-i-i}=2 \pi$$

---

As with regards to the question in bold, everything depends on the final result of applying [residue theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem), assuming $f(z)$ meets the inputs of the theorem. $(1)$ is a particular case of it, to some extent. But the integral may evaluate to a complex number, in which case *larger number* [doesn't make sense](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1116022/can-a-complex-number-ever-be-considered-bigger-or-smaller-than-a-real-number).

Comment: Perfect. Thank you for the link to the discussion on comparing the “size” of real and complex numbers! And obviously, I misunderstood where to use Cauchy’s Integral formula, so thanks for that!